# Using a logo image in a WordPress blog

Tags: html, wordpress

In the code below, I am using an image `images/newlogo.PNG` for a logo.  I am trying to add the same logo to a WordPress blog, but WordPress can't seem to find the logo. Any idea where I should put the image so that WordPress can find it?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
<div class="newlogo">
    <a href="index.php">
        <img src="images/newlogo.PNG" alt="Books" border="0"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an 'absolute' path (relative to the server) like this:

```
<img src="/images/newlogo.PNG" alt="Books" border="0"/>
```

You just need to put the image in the *images* folder in the root of the server

Comment: That's the thing-- they are in the images folder, and it works fine for my site.  But for the Wordpress blog, it doesn't.

Comment: John, the path in your example is not an absolute path - it's missing the leading slash.

Answer (score 3):

My experiece with WordPress is many times you need the full path for images called outside of the style sheet, because your full path is something like username/public_html/wordpresshere

Best to put images in your theme so they stay put whn you change themes or go along when you download/backup themes

So, hardcode your full path from your URL, or:

```
Use this to return site URL:

<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/themes/default/images/newlogo.png


Or this to return the current template directory:

<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/newlogo.png



Like this:

<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/newlogo.PNG" alt="Books" border="0"/>
```

Comment: Yup, this is the answer. You need that line of php to tell wordpress what the actual page is: <?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>

Comment: Yes, 'template_directory' throws the path for the current theme. But in the CSS of each theme's style sheet - no matter the current or others that are not activated - you can use the path images/newlogo.png, because the images are one directory down from the style sheet, i.e.

`
body
{
background: url(images/newlogo.png) repeat;
font-size: small;
font-family:Verdana, Tahoma, Arial, Serif;
color: #000;
font-size:0.7em;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you need to have the file in the wp-content folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding this code into a theme file, you need to use the path to the image directory within the theme directory. This can be done by using `get_template_directory_uri()`.

Here is an example:

```
<div class="newlogo">
    <a href="index.php">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>images/newlogo.PNG" alt="Books" border="0"/>
    </a>
</div>
```